# How to delete an array that a function returns

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, heap-memory

I am new to C++ and I'm having a small memory leak issue. The structure of my program is very simple, as shown below, although I have left out parts that are irrelevant to the problem.

```
int** foo(int sizeOfArray){

     int** arrayToReturn = new int*[sizeOfArray];

     for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++) {
           arrayToReturn[i] = new int[2];
     }
     return arrayToReturn;
}

int main() {       
    a = someNumber;                // 'a' can be any value ( < 64)
    int** someArray = foo(int a);
    // Do stuff with someArray
}
```

So essentially, it calls a function that returns an array of arrays. My problem is that when my program calls this function thousands of times, they cause a memory leak because since I am using NEW, I need to use delete. I'm just not sure how to delete the arrays, as I need to use them in the main function so I can't delete them within the function foo, but how do I delete them afterwards? I tried just deleting `someArray`, but the memory used up from the line `arrayToReturn[i] = new int[2]` is never freed.

Hopefully that makes sense, I am sorry if it's a stupid question, and thanks for reading!

Comment: don't use raw pointers, use c++ pointer classes like 'std::unique_ptr'.  Additionally, if that is what you are actually shooting for, then using a std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> rather than doing it yourself would also be much better

Comment: I have never used either of vector or unique_ptr, will they both deallocate themselves once out of scope? Are they easy to learn to use? And is there no way of achieving what I want with raw pointers?

Comment: @MatthewFennell Both are way easier than learning manual memory management.

Comment: @MatthewFennell: The compiler will insert the correct calls to the copy constructor and destructor, to make their use as easy as using an integer. Both destructors (vector and unique_ptr) will then clean up the managed resources. With raw pointers, you have to invoke the right destructors, and it turns out humans aren't as good at bookkeeping as compilers are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters you have to delete pointers in the reverse order relative to their allocations.

You can write a function that will do the task the following way

```
void free( int **array, int sizeOfArray )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++ ) 
    {
        delete [] array[i];
    }

    delete [] array;
}
```

Or it can be even defined like

```
void free( int ** &array, int sizeOfArray )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++ ) 
    {
        delete [] array[i];
    }

    delete [] array;

    array = nullptr;
}
```

Instead of allocating and freeing memory yourself you could use standard class `std::vector` declared in header `<vector>`

For example your array could be defined like

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> array( sizeOfArray, std::vector<int>( 2 ) );
```

In this case you need not to bother about freeing memory.

Comment: isn't the for loop only necessary for 2D arrays?

Comment: @APA In fact there is simulated a 2D array.

Comment: For a 1D array , wouldn't delete [] arr; suffice?

Comment: And why do you need a pointer to a pointer to a reference?

Comment: @APA Please reread the question and the  answer.

Answer (score 3):

To completely delete the array, including the sub-arrays within it, you could do the following:

```
// Assuming we have an array called 'array'
int** array = foo(bar);

// Iterate through all the sub-arrays and delete them
for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++) {    
   delete [] array[i];
}

// Delete the primary array
delete [] array;
```

There are some style problems with this code, and some people might try to tell you to never use raw pointers, but I just wanted to answer the question in a straight-forward fashion for you.

It is basically the opposite order of operations that you used to create the array. First you created the outer array, then you iterated through and created the sub arrays, for deletion you need to first delete the sub-arrays and then delete the outermost array.

Answer (score 1):

This is not great C++, I can't remember the last time I've used new and delete on an array it's so long ago. But granted you need to know how it works when you're learning so push on with it and good luck!

Here's the relevant code for an array of `int`s:

```
int* foo = new int[20];
// free the array
delete [] foo;
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem though. I need a way of deleting the array when I'm no longer in the scope where it was created.

Comment: Note that OP's question is about a jagged array, so this answer is a bit simplistic.

Comment: yeah, by design. It looks like homework to me. If you have a pointer to the start of the array you can delete the whole array with delete [] ptr. Knowing this you can apply it to an array of arrays or whatever else.

Comment: @MatthewFennell being the scope is irrelevant. If you have the pointer to the start of the array you can delete it. This is not good, idiomatic C++

Answer (score 0):

Standard solution to this problem is don't take this path in the first place.

[`std::vector` is the one stop shop for all your dynamic array needs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and[`std::array` stands in for the static array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). Taken together, we get a nice 2 dimensional array that happens to be contiguous in memory and will be released the instant it goes out of scope.

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>

std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> foo(int sizeOfArray){

    return std::vector<std::array<int, 2>>(sizeOfArray);
}

int main() {
    int a = 50; // your number here
    std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> someArray = foo(a);
    // Do stuff with someArray


} //someArray goes out of scope and is destoyed, freeing all of the allocated memory
```

Answer (score 0):

See the 'deleteArray' function. You pretty much have to delete the sub arrays first. Then you delete the top level array. Learning memory management is a good skill to have. Once you learn memory management (using 'new' and 'delete') you should learn about the STL containers. In practice people will use STL.

I also added a print function so you can see what it looks like.

```
#include <iostream>

int** foo(int sizeOfArray){
    int** arrayToReturn = new int*[sizeOfArray];

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++) { 
        arrayToReturn[i] = new int[2];
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            arrayToReturn[i][j] = j;
        } 
    } 

    return arrayToReturn;
}

void printArray(int **array, int sizeOfArray){
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            std::cout << array[i][j] << " "; 

        } 
        std::cout <<  std::endl;
    } 
}

void deleteArray(int **array, int sizeOfArray){
    // Do the inverse of foo
    // Delete the sub arrays (ones with size 2)
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++){
        delete [] array[i];
    }

    // Then delete the entire array
    delete [] array;
}       

int main(){
    int a = 34;
    int **someArray = foo(a);
    printArray(someArray, a);

    std::cout << someArray << std::endl;

    // Delete pieces of memory
    deleteArray(someArray, a);

    // Readability as well. Set our local reference to NULL
    // Also, will make sure we can't use someArray elsewhere
    someArray = NULL;


    // This 'printArray' call would cause a segfault 
    // printArray(someArray, a);

    return 0;
}
```